# Using XMLHttpRequest, I am trying to build a blog with comments next to it

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Blogs link: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
Comments link: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments
I can display blogs but when I am trying to link comments in same row that of blogs I am messing it up.
Ideally each row of table will have one post and five comments next to it.

Thanks for help in advance.

//Code I am trying:

```
function showBlogs(){
    let str = "";
    let bposts = blogPosts();
     
    function blogPosts(){
        
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        request.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(request.readyState===4 && request.status===200){
                let items = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++){
                    str =str + "<tr>" + "<td>" + items[i].id + ". "+ items[i].title + "<br>" + 
                    items[i].body + "<br>" + "</td>" ;
                    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    let str2 = "";
                    let requestComm = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    requestComm.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments');
                    requestComm.onreadystatechange=function(){
                        if(requestComm.readyState===4 && requestComm.status===200){
                            let itemsComm = JSON.parse(requestComm.responseText);
                            str2 = "";
                            for(let j=0; j<itemsComm.length; j++){
                                if(items[i].id == itemsComm[j].postId){
                                    str2 = str2  + "<td>" + itemsComm[j].postId + "<br>" + 
                                 itemsComm[j].id + ". "+ itemsComm[j].name + itemsComm[j].email + " 
                                 <br>" + itemsComm[j].body + "</td>" ;
                                }
                                
                                str = str + str2 + "</tr>";
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                    
                    requestComm.send();
                    document.getElementById('blogs').innerHTML = str;
                }    
            }
        }
        request.send();    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous so by the time that call is made, the outside loop is already passed it.